# Hugo escapes Javascript in partial, code gets broken

Tags: javascript, mathjax, hugo

This snippet is published in [MathJax](https://gohugo.io/tutorials/mathjax/) support page in Hugo. I take it and insert into a partial (say, `head.html`).

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(function() {
    // Fix <code> tags after MathJax finishes running. This is a
    // hack to overcome a shortcoming of Markdown. Discussion at
    // https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/199
    var all = MathJax.Hub.getAllJax(), i;
    for(i = 0; i < all.length; i += 1) {
        all[i].SourceElement().parentNode.className += ' has-jax';
    }
});
</script>
```

When the page loads, the browser tries to execute it, but writes an exception in Console:

```
VM14379:7 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
at eval (<anonymous>)
```

I click that line and see this:

[image]

Am I right that it's because `<` was escaped? How to fix it?

(**edit:** moving this to `my-theme/layouts/index.html` made the code disappear from the rendered page completely. In `layouts/_default/single.html` it still causes the same error.)

Hugo version is 0.21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution: changed `type="text/x-mathjax-config"` to `type="text/javascript"`, and everything worked perfectly.